# javascript:void(0) on ajax pagination code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm developing this pagination page with ajax on code igniter hmvc but  I get this `javascript:void(0)` on the uri of my link to the next pages. how can  I fix this?

here is my codes.

controllers

```
<?php

class Job_Titles extends MY_Controller{

    public function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Job_Titles_Model');
        $this->load->library('Ajax_pagination');
        $this->perPage = 10;

    }

// VIEW REDIRECTING /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function index(){

    /// view ajax config/////

        $data = array();

    //total row count
        $totalRec = count($this->Job_Titles_Model->getRows());

    //configuration
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['div'] = 'postList'; //parent div tag id
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Job_Titles/ajaxPaginationData';
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page'] = $this->perPage; 

        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['content_view'] = 'Job_Titles/jobtitles_read';
        $data['content'] = $this->Job_Titles_Model->getRows(array('limit'=>$this->perPage));
        $data['false'] = FALSE;
        $this->templates->admin_template($data);

    }


    //// pagination

    public function ajaxPaginationData(){

        $data = array();
        $page = $this->input->post('page');
            if(!$page){
                $offset = 0;
            }else{
                $offset = $page;
            }

        //total row count
        $totalRec = count($this->Job_Titles_Model->getRows());

        //pagination config
        $config['first_link'] = 'First';
        $config['base_url'] = base_url().'Job_Titles/ajaxPaginationData';
        $config['total_rows'] = $totalRec;
        $config['per_page'] = $this->perPage; 

        $this->ajax_pagination->initialize($config);

        //get post data
        $data['content_view'] = 'Job_Titles/ajax-pagination-data';
        $data['content'] = $this->Job_Titles_Model->getRows(array('start'=>$offset,'limit'=>$this->perPage));

        $this->templates->admin_template($data);

    }
}
```

models

```
    public function getRows($params = array()){

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->table);

    if(array_key_exists("start", $params) && array_key_exists("limit", $params)){

        $this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
    }elseif (!array_key_exists("start", $params) && array_key_exists("limit", $params)) {
        $this->db->limit($params['limit']);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();

    return ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
    }
```

views

```
<?php

echo anchor('Job_Titles/add_view','ADD ');  

?>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "container" class = "page-header">
    <table class= "table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>JOB CODE</th>
                <th>JOB NAME</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php if(!empty($content)){foreach ($content as $job_title) {?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $job_title['JOB_CODE']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $job_title['JOB_NAME']; ?></td>

                    <td><a href=''><i class="fa  fa-edit"></a></i></td>
                    <td><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></td> 
                </tr>

            <?php }}else{ ?>
            <li class="err_msg">Post(s) not available.</li>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php echo $this->ajax_pagination->create_links(); ?>
</div>
```

I'm developing this pagination page with ajax on code igniter hmvc but  I get this `javascript:void(0)` on the uri of my link to the next pages. how can  I fix this?

Comment: store the one variable for o $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();  in controller and show in view file. Can you show the link of pagination ?

Comment: how will i store  variable for  $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();? please explain it to me. i didnt get it. sorry

Comment: $data['pagniation_link'] = $this->ajax_pagination->create_links();

Comment: i will put it to? then i will print_r it?

Comment: echo $data['pagniation_link']; show the the link of pagination numbers

Comment: Showing 1 to 10 of 13 |  1 2 >  but its not a link. haha

Comment: oh. where from you get this code ? If you click this pagination number, then any request goto controller check in console

Comment: i got it from here http://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-in-codeigniter-framework/ i just modified it. can you please help me? im new to this thing. haha.

Comment: any request goto controller check in console

Comment: please further explanation sir. thank you. :)

Comment: If you click the pagination link, then goto call to controller. check in console

Comment: can you give me codes or sample codes for it?

Comment: I say check in console http://www.codexworld.com/ajax-pagination-in-codeigniter-framework/